# Which are the included fonts in Android 4.x?

Tags: android, css, gmail

I'm generating HTML-mails and as such, need to fall back to inline styling.
As a result, it's not possible (or hard?) to use @font-face and I need to rely on font-style or font-family.

It's working alright, but using "Impact" (required), is a problem since I can't find an Android replacement. Is there one? Is there a list of the fonts that the gmail app can render?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fonts.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'd say "fonts" are about typography and readability. But the question is pure technical.